# How to remove unwanted functions from interface

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have an interface class `MyFunction`. There are three functions in this class with the following signatures:

```
virtual bool Eval(int& iReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList) = 0;
virtual bool Eval(double& dReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList) = 0;
virtual bool Eval(char*& zReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList) = 0;
```

Now, any implementation of `MyFunction` will only need to implement one of these functions depending on what type of value it needs to return. But I'll have to implement all 3 functions even if the other two functions are like this:

```
virtual bool Eval(double& dReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList){return false;}
```

which doesnt look so good. Or, I can declare all three functions like this in the interface:

```
virtual bool Eval(int& iReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList){return false;}
virtual bool Eval(double& dReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList){return false;}
virtual bool Eval(char*& zReturnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList){return false;}
```

Which also looks ugly. What is the less ugly of these two? Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

On D Krueger's method :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
            void F(T){cout << "Type T" << endl;}
};

class Imp : public Base
{
    public:
        template<int>
            void F(int){cout << "Type int" << endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Base* pB;
    Imp oI;
    pB = &oI;

    pB->F(1);
}
```

Looks like specialization does not apply across classes though derived. As template functions can't be virtual, this is a hopeless situation it seems.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is something like `boost::variant<int, double, char>` for the parameter of a single function.

Comment: no boost please. :). Can't use it. I want something I can build on my own.

Comment: If your interface has other pure virtual functions, go with the second. You won't get any more "purity" from having more pure virtual functions, and you'll get the effect you desire. If you want you might be able to work up some trick to make sure at least one of the `Eval()` functions can return true, but this may be black magic.

Comment: I would suggest throwing an exception in the virtual base class implementations to reinforce your statement that they won't be used unless you override them.

Comment: If any class derived from this Interface class will need only one of these functions, why do you want the base class to declare all three?

Comment: Some information would help. What is the purpose of the derived classes? Do they solely implement Eval()? Will the number of derived classes always be the same as the number of Eval() functions? Does the MyFunction class call Eval()?

Comment: @Beta: Just because any implementation class will need only one function doesn't mean that they'll all use the same function.

Comment: @D Krueger: Yes, the purpose of derived classes is to provide an implementation (only 1) of `Eval()`.

Comment: @xscott: What's the advantage of throwing instead of leaving them pure virtual?? Aren't you moving the check from compile time to runtime (which I wouldn't consider helpful)?

Comment: But *why declare them in the base class?* Are you planning to try calling these functions using a pointer to MyFunction, without knowing the actual type?

Comment: It is hard to think of any C++ program existing without Boost :(

Comment: @Philipp: You won't be able to instantiate the derived classes unless they implement all of the methods which were specified pure in the base class(es).  Since he only wants to specify one of these methods per derived class (perhaps along with the member data that is particular to that derived class), he'll have to provide *some* implementation for the other pure virtual methods.  In this case, returning false is a quieter runtime failure than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is a one-to-one mapping between the types used in Eval() and the number of implementations, a template member function should work.

```
class MyFunction {

    template <class T>
    bool Eval(T& returnVal, size_t szArgumentCount, list<Param> lParameterList) 
        { return false; }
};
```

Then implement the specializations for the types that shouldn't return false.

This requires only the single generic implementation to return false and the three implementations that would be needed in any case.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, Implementations of `MyFunction` will reside in a shared object. does this cause a problem?

Comment: If the implementations need access to the same member variables (to save state for example) then it could be a problem. Otherwise, it should be fine.

Comment: Now it is clear to me. For template specialization to work in this case, the specializations have to be in the base class because that is what the compiler sees. Otherwise, we'd be asking for template functionality at run time (Derived class is only available then). :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a sign that your interface-design could need to be refactored, when the classes implementing the interface did not need the whole amount of methods in it. Perhaps you could divide this interface into 3 interfaces.

Another possibility would be to create a wrapper-interface from that, which returns default values for the unneeded 2 methods. But in this case you would end up with 3 interfaces as well (and the original parent-interface -> 4 interfaces total). This solution would be acceptable if you have no possibility of changing the original interface.

Comment: Yes I can declare a `template<typename T> class MyFunction` and use the three specializations. But, the problem is I have to create objects from all the three types from a factory and store in a collection. Or perhaps I will have to give it up.

Comment: Then I would prefer the first solution (implementing the methods in the class, returning false). An interface whose methods are not needed to be implemented isn't an interface in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off declaring a single pure virtual method to override, but have it return a discriminated union or variant/any type in that first argument.  Then each derived class can return the type it wants.  With your current way, you were going to need to make a decision on which method to call.  With a discriminated union, you'll only call the one method, but make the decision about what to do with it after it returns.

```
double dd;
int ii;
char* ss;
switch (ptr->type) {
    case DOUBLE:  ptr->Eval(&dd, ...); break;
    case INTEGER: ptr->Eval(&ii, ...); break;
    case STRING:  ptr->Eval(&ss, ...); break;
}
```

becomes something like:

```
double dd;
int ii;
char* ss;
variant vv;
ptr->Eval(&vv, ...);
switch (vv.type) {
    case DOUBLE:  dd = vv.dd; break;
    case INTEGER: ii = vv.ii; break;
    case STRING:  ss = vv.ss; break;
}
```

Obviously I've skipped the error checking and the like, but it's pretty similar to what I think you're planning to do.